# If conditional with or

Tags: php

Here is my script:

```
$user_data = user_data($name);

        if($user_data['type'] == 'clerk') { 
        } elseif ($user_data['type'] == 'admin' ){
        }else
        { header("Location: login_admin1.php");}

    }
```

If I am using an if statement with blank `{}` it works but as soon as I use this script it's not working.

```
 if($user_data['type'] != 'clerk' || $user_data['type'] != 'admin')
{ header("Location: login_admin1.php");}
```

I want to check if `$user_data['type']` is clerk or admin, (only clerk or  admin has access to page) can check page. If it's not one of them they can't access the page.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)?

```
if ( ! in_array( $user_data['type'], array( "clerk", "admin" ) ) ) {
  // Is neither Clerk, nor Admin.
}
```

Cuts down on having to write `$user_data['type']` over and over.

Comment: yaa its working but littel error in ur code its missing ) thx

Comment: if ( ! in_array( $user_data['type'], array( "clerk", "admin" ) ) )

Answer (score 3):

Use `&&` instead of `||` in `if` statement:

Try:

```
if( $user_data['type'] != 'clerk' && $user_data['type'] != 'admin' ) { 
    header("Location: login_admin1.php");
}
```